# How to extract lowest level of a nested JSON into a DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, extract

I'm looking to extract only the lowest-level objects of a JSON in Python. For example, the first few records from API look something like this:

```
{
  "season": 2021,
  "charts": {
    "ARI": {
      "TE": [
        {
          "team": "ARI",
          "position": "TE",
          "depth": "1",
          "playerId": "1443",
          "name": "Dan Arnold"
        },
        {
          "team": "ARI",
          "position": "TE",
          "depth": "2",
          "playerId": "599",
          "name": "Maxx Williams"
        }
      ],
      "K": [
        {
          "team": "ARI",
          "position": "K",
          "depth": "1",
          "playerId": "1121",
          "name": "Zane Gonzalez"
        },
        {
```

I ultimately want to get all of these results into a DataFrame that has this structure:

```
| team | position | depth | playerId | name |
|:---- |:-------- |:----- |:-------- |:---- |
```

I've tried variations of the following code without success:

```
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd

# Retrieve Depth Charts
json_depthCharts = rq.get(f"https://api.fantasynerds.com/v1/nfl/depth?apikey={API_KEY}").json()

df_depthCharts = pd.json_normalize(json_depthCharts, 'charts', ['charts', 'team'])

print(df_depthCharts)
```

Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: Also The link you provided is helpful but your API key is visible in it so pls remove it and pls in future if you have such big data then either paste it in on sites like pastebin or share  through any other medium that doesn't exploit sensitive  information

Comment: Sir did your query solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `json_normalize()`+`melt()`+`explode()`+`Dataframe()`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(json_depthCharts).melt('season')['value'].explode().tolist())
```

**OR**

other way via `stack()`+`drop()` combination in place of `melt()` and rest all methods remains same:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(json_depthCharts).drop(columns='season').stack().explode().tolist())
```

output of `df`:

```
        team    position    depth   playerId    name
0       ARI     TE          1       1443        Dan Arnold
1       ARI     TE          2       599         Maxx Williams
2       ARI     K           1       1121        Zane Gonzalez
3       ARI     K           2       1454        Brett Maher
4       ARI     LWR         1       338         DeAndre Hopkins
...     ...     ...        ...      ...         ...
932     WAS     LDE         2       179         Ryan Kerrigan
933     WAS     RCB         1       647         Ronald Darby
934     WAS     RB          1       1957        Antonio Gibson
935     WAS     RB          2       1542        Bryce Love
936     WAS     NB          1       1733        Jimmy Moreland

937 rows × 5 columns
```